# Cloudfiles API with SNET set to true seems very slow

Tags: php, rackspace, cloudfiles

So I did as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399072/rackspace-cloudfiles-api-fairly-slow).

But I'm still seeing some pretty slow responses when getting URLs for files stored in containers on cloudfiles.

The application I'm building has a portion where users can comment.  Each user has a profile image which shows up next to their comment.  The basic structure of the code is as follows:

```
1) Authenticate cloudfiles api
2) Open connection
3) Retrieve main users profile image
4) Retrieve all comments from database
   4.1) Loop through users comments
   4.2) Get container and file name from DB
   4.3) Retrieve image from CloudFiles
5) Close connection
```

I have SNET as true and I am on a Rackspace server but, it seems to crawl in comparison to  when I stored them directly on the server.  Also the reason I am not storing the public url in the database is due to the user being able to change their image and me wanting to store past images, therefore not overwriting the past image.   I could store each past image's url as well as the new images and probably will do that but, wanted to see how fast I could get it prior to doing that.

The reason I am hesitant to go straight to storing each images public url is because on another portion of the site I am going to use Temp URLs for some secure files and am trying to see if I can fix the performance in general.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Ron - can you quantify "crawl in comparison" for me? I'll spin up some servers and do some testing. Are you using the php-opencloud library or hitting the API directly?

Comment: Chris, I am using the php-opencloud library.  By crawl it went from near instantaneous retrieval to taking about 3-5 seconds.  Once the URL is loading it flies it's just getting the URL to post.

Comment: Ron - I've done some research on this issue and there appears to be a file based limit on pushing files into a CF container so I'm wondering if there might not be an API limit you are bumping up against with regards to getting container and object data that is asymmetric in it's behavior with regards to SNET or direct access. Can you post a gist of any of the code so that is consistent in my testing?

Comment: You're a racker correct?  If so want to open a support ticket and I can post everything in there?

Comment: I am, but I'm still waiting for access to that ticketing system. You can email it to me though: chris.rasco [at] rackspace.com

Comment: Ron - I have access to our ticketing system now if you want to submit a ticket with code samples and you can email me the ticket number if you'd like.